# Why applying the second law of motion gives me the wrong value of tangential acceleration in vertical circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Let's take two small masses from the rod, $dm$ each. One from the point $A$ and another from the point $B$. Now both the masses would have two forces acting on it i.e. tension and $(dm)g$.
[image]

From applying second law of motion on each of the masses we will get this same equation:

$dm(a_{tangential})=(dm)g sin\theta$

But this equation is implying that both the small masses would have equal tangential acceleration but we clearly know from $a_{tangential}=\alpha r$ that the tangential acceleration would be dependent on the distance from the axis.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your sketch.

There are additional internal shear forces in this object (that is why if you try to bend it, it will remain straight).  Ropes too will have some shear, though they behave differently.  Sometimes you get away with ignoring it, other times you don't.

This is what you might expect (note for simplicity I omitted gravity). $V$ is the shear. $d(\cdot)$ is some kind of differential change.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you draw or describe a better sketch and how these shear forces may be acting? I remember using small dm masses like these in derivations for some formulae in elasticity and don't remember drawing shear forces like you are describing.

Comment: @Swan sure. see update

Comment: @Swan its common to ignore them, but here they are crucial -- these shear forces are fundamentally what transfer the force throughout this rigid body.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Imagining a rod kept horizontally helped me visualise these shear forces. If kept horizontally all the tangential acceleration would be provided by these shear forces alone.